# Why does this compile in Java?

Tags: java, generics

Why does this compile?

B is used in A without any generic parameters, and this compiled in Java. What is going on here?

```
interface B<T>
{
    public T Foo(T value);
}

public class A
{
    public B What()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        B x = What();
        x.Foo(123);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're just using a `raw` type of `B` here. Just like

```
 List list = new ArrayList(); // defined as: public interface List<E>
```

Perfectly, valid; not recommended though.

Comment: What type of object can `list` have added to it? Is everything just treated as `Object`?

Comment: Yes, using a raw type means any object can be added to it. So, if you had a list of `String` (without generics) the compiler won't complain if you later tried to add an `Integer` to it.

Comment: @nachokk It's not the same, the compiler processes expressions with raw types a little differently. (It's probably close enough though.)

Comment: @nachokk: It's not the same. You can assign a `List<String>` to a `List`, but cannot assign a `List<String>` to a `List<Object>`.

Answer (score 9):

This is for compatibility with pre-J2SE 5.0 Java. You should get a rawtypes warning (take notice of the compiler warnings).

Comment: @HotLicks If you compile to native code, everything is a compiler fiction.

Comment: @SteveP. It works because the language is designed this way, and compilers follow the spec. Erasure is a mapping between the full type system of 1.5 to the pre-1.5 subset. The mapping is used in various ways (not all of which concern runtime types!) in the language.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - No, the JVM enforces most type checking, but knows nothing of generics.  Similar to inner classes.

Comment: @HotLicks The JVM is pretty much irrelevant, other than forcing weird contortions on the Java language.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - One could turn that argument on its ear.  javac and some of the junk that's been added to it forces the JVM through weird contortions.